# User can't SFTP after chroot

Tags: sftp, chroot

Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

I'm trying to chroot the user 'sam'. According to all the articles out there this should work, but apparently I'm still doing something wrong.

The user:

```
sam:x:1005:1006::/home/sam:/bin/false
```

I changed /etc/ssh/sshd_config like this (at the bottom of the file):

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
# CHROOT JAIL
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group users
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

I added sam to the users group:

```
$groups sam
sam : sam users
```

I changed the permissions for sam's home folder:

```
$ ls -la /home/sam
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  4096 Sep 23 16:12 .
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root  4096 Sep 22 16:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 sam  users 4096 Sep 23 16:10 awstats
drwxr-xr-x  3 sam  users 4096 Sep 23 16:10 etc
...
drwxr-xr-x  2 sam  users 4096 Sep 23 16:10 homes
drwxr-x---  3 sam  users 4096 Sep 23 16:10 public_html
```

I restarted ssh and now sam can't log in with SFTP. The session is created, but also closed immediately:

```
Sep 24 12:55:15 ... sshd[9917]: Accepted password for sam from  ...
Sep 24 12:55:15 ... sshd[9917]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user sam  by (uid=0)
Sep 24 12:55:16 ... sshd[9928]: subsystem request for sftp
Sep 24 12:55:17 ... sshd[9917]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user sam
```

Cyberduck says `Unexpected end of sftp stream.` and other clients give similar errors.

What did I forget / what is going wrong?

Thanks!

---

Edit

I couldn't get it to work, even after contacting the OpenSSH mailinglist, so I decided to reset my entire server (which was a viable option, fortunately). It's working now.

Comment: It would be best if you put the resolution as an answer and accepted it, to make what happened clear to any future visitors.

Comment: If that's the prefered way at serverfault, I'll add it.

Comment: the problem is `sam`'s home is supposed to be `/home/sam`, but under the chroot there isn't any `/home/sam`, so sftp can't put the user into its home upon login and exits (without a good error message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though jaume's answer is very nice, it couldn't help me in the end. I tried the OpenSSH mailinglist, but no luck there. I ended up resetting my entire server, which I could still do fortunately. It's working perfectly now.

Comment: I guess we will never find out where exactly the problem was, I couldn't it figure out despite all your feedback, great you got it running.

Comment: I have the exact same issue now. Trying to find out why its happening. Dont want to give up and reset the server just yet..

Comment: Well this accepted answer is useless for the SF community.

Answer (score 5):

Your setup definitely looks good, let's see if we can find out where the problem is.

1. Check that your openSSH version supports `ChrootDirectory`:

   Support for the `ChrootDirectory` keyword was added to openSSH
   version 4.8p1 ( http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/590 ).
   Check that at least that version is installed:

   ```
   dpkg --list openssh-server
   ```

   *[This is probably not the cause, according to http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-server-amd64.list
   openssh-server's version is 5.3p1]*
2. Test SFTP locally.

   Type in a terminal on your Ubuntu computer:

   ```
   sftp sam@localhost
   ```

   and see whether you can log in (you must type sam's password when
   asked). If it works there may be a problem with Cyberduck's
   configuration.

   If you can't log in, try SFTP without chroot.
3. Test SFTP locally without chroot.

   Prefix this:

   ```
   Match group users
       ChrootDirectory %h
       ForceCommand internal-sftp
       AllowTcpForwarding no
   ```

   with `#` to comment it out, restart sshd (`sudo service ssh
   restart`) and then type:

   ```
   sftp sam@localhost
   ```

   Type the password when asked and see whether you can log in. If you
   can log in troubleshoot the chroot configuration as follows: try
   step 2 again with command `sftp -vvv sam@localhost` for verbose
   output. You can also increase `sshd`'s log level by adding `LogLevel
   VERBOSE` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restarting `sshd`. Hopefully
   you see something obvious in the console or in `/var/log/auth.log`.

   If you can't log in, try SSH.
4. Test SSH locally.

   SFTP requires a working SSH, so change sam's shell to /bin/bash:

   ```
   sudo usermod -s /bin/bash sam
   ```

   and try:

   ```
   ssh sam@localhost
   ```

   Type sam's password when asked. If you can log in try increasing
   verbosity as explained in 3) to find out what's wrong (`sftp -vvv
   sam@localhost` and `LogLevel VERBOSE` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`). 
   Another possibility is that the shell initialization confuses the
   sftp client ( http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#2.9 ):

   > 2.9 - sftp/scp fails at connection, but ssh is OK.
   >
   > sftp and/or scp may fail at connection time if you have shell initialization 
   >   (.profile, .bashrc, .cshrc, etc) which produces output for non-interactive sessions. 
   >   This output confuses the sftp/scp client. You can verify if your shell is doing this
   >   by executing:
   >
   > ```
   > ssh yourhost /usr/bin/true
   > ```
   >
   > If the above command produces any output, then you need to modify your shell initialization.

   If you can't log in, try `ssh root@localhost`. If doesn't work
   either there's something wrong with `sshd` on the server. Increase
   verbosity (`LogLevel VERBOSE` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), restart
   `sshd` and peruse `/var/log/auth.log`, the answer is probably there.

Comment: Thanks for this guide. I'm able to log in without chroot, but the -vvv isn't really giving me much. I've put the output on [pastebin.com/](http://pastebin.com/vMaPr26L) . Does anyone else see anything weird?

I created a new 'test' user and followed all the steps again, but the result is exactly the same (sftp works, but not with chroot)

Comment: Can you post /var/log/auth.log?

Comment: And what is your openssh-server version? (dpkg --list openssh-server)

Comment: My version is 1:5.3p1-3ubuntu7. I've posted /var/log/auth.log [here](http://pastebin.com/xfAd6C00) (log level is VERBOSE in ./etc/ssh/sshd_config)

Answer (score 4):

Centos 7 - I had the same issue - I tried everything under the sun to diagnose it - eventually I changed the sftp subsystem in '/etc/ssh/sshd_conf', restarted sshd (`service sshd restart`) and the problem was fixed :

From :

```
#Subsystem      sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

To :

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

I've no idea why two implementation are provided

Comment: Hello, it wasn't the same issue as OP alerady had "Subsystem sftp internal-sftp" enabled.

Comment: In fact only the internal-sftp allows chroot. The external sftp server has more options, though.

Comment: Thanks @wazoox - I wasn't aware of the distinction between the two.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, resolved by setting the chroot-dir to owner root and group root.

`chown root:root chroot-dir`

Comment: This worked for me as well (CentOS), BUT only in conjunction with changing the permissions on the chroot-dir: `chmod 555 <chroot-dir>`  Any other permission combination I tried netted the error and broken connection.

Answer (score -1):

1. For "connection refused" error check the "UsePAM yes" setting in sshd_config. 
   It must be BEFORE "Subsystem sftp"
2. For authentication problems check that EACH directory in chroot-path owned by root and has permissions 755 or less.

Example: ChrootDirectory /var/www/data

You have to check permissions and owner for: /var, /var/www, /var/www/data

3. For weird problems like "connection is closed after authentication" try to update or change SFTP-server.

apt-get install openssh-server

"Subsystem sftp internal-sftp" <-> "Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server" (switch from the type with your problems to another one)